# Error: Cause: compileSdkVersion is not specified after install plugin

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I tried to install this [plugin](https://github.com/stephanenicolas/ormlite-android-gradle-plugin). firstly i got

`Can not add task 'clean' as a task with that name already exists.`

then I fixed it by commented this lines

```
//
//task clean(type: Delete) {
//    delete rootProject.buildDir
//}
```

in the **build.gradle (Project:XXX)**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
        classpath 'com.github.stephanenicolas.ormgap:ormgap-plugin:1.0.13'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'ormgap'

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
//
//task clean(type: Delete) {
//    delete rootProject.buildDir
//}
```

then I got error

`Cause: compileSdkVersion is not specified.`
even thoght it's already specified in build.gradle file

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "www.pro_cs_is.com"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:exifinterface:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation ('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2',{
    exclude group: 'com.google.code.findbugs'})
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.11.3'
    implementation 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-blogger:v3-rev57-1.23.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:5.1'
    implementation 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-core:5.1'
}
```

Comment: don't apply the plugins in the root project's `build.gradle` ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- apply plugins in
- build.gradle(module:app) only
- As follows

  ```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
  apply plugin: 'ormgap'

  android {
  compileSdkVersion 27
  buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
  useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
  defaultConfig {
  applicationId "www.pro_cs_is.com"
  minSdkVersion 15
  targetSdkVersion 27
  versionCode 1
  versionName "1.0"
  testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
  }
  buildTypes {
  release {
      minifyEnabled false
      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-   rules.pro'
     }
     }
     }

    dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:exifinterface:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation ('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2',{
    exclude group: 'com.google.code.findbugs'})
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.11.3'
    implementation 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-blogger:v3-rev57-1.23.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:5.1'
    implementation 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-core:5.1'
   }
  ```
- and remove it from build.gradle(project:XXX)
- I hope this will be help